# How say FolderOverlay in osmbonuspack to take style from JSON?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I use osmbonuspack in my project. Incoming GeoJson has fields "style":

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":
    [{"type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
          "coordinates":[[.......]],
          "type":"Polygon"},
      "properties":{"id":1433861787198,
      "monitoring_in":false,
      "emergency_message_in":false,
      "monitoring_out":false,
      "emergency_message_out":false,
      "send_notification":false,
      "style":{"stroke":true,
           "color":"#0033ff",
           "weight":5.0,
           "opacity":0.5,
           "fill":true,
           "fillOpacity":0.2,
           "clickable":true}}}
```

but when I put it on map all figures are black (without style or default style)

```
        KmlDocument kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();

        kmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(str);

        FolderOverlay kmlOverlay = (FolderOverlay) kmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(mMapView, null, null, kmlDocument);

        mMapView.getOverlays().add(kmlOverlay);

        mMapView.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. Now only for polygones, I haven't another objects in file.

```
private void showGeoJsonObjects(String str){

    KmlDocument kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();

    kmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(str);

    //Add styler
    KmlFeature.Styler styler = new MyKmlStyler();

    FolderOverlay kmlOverlay = (FolderOverlay) kmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(mMapView, null, styler, kmlDocument);

    mMapView.getOverlays().add(kmlOverlay);

    mMapView.invalidate();
}


class MyKmlStyler implements KmlFeature.Styler {
    @Override
    public void onFeature(Overlay overlay, KmlFeature kmlFeature) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPoint(Marker marker, KmlPlacemark kmlPlacemark, KmlPoint kmlPoint) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLineString(Polyline polyline, KmlPlacemark kmlPlacemark, KmlLineString kmlLineString) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPolygon(Polygon polygon, KmlPlacemark kmlPlacemark, KmlPolygon kmlPolygon) {
        try {
            String styleString = kmlPlacemark.getExtendedData("style");
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(styleString);
            if(o.getBoolean("stroke")) {
                String colorHash = "#"+Integer.toHexString((int)(o.getDouble("opacity")*255))+o.getString("color").replace("#","");
                polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.parseColor(colorHash));
                polygon.setStrokeWidth((float) o.getDouble("weight"));
            }
            if(o.getBoolean("fill")){
                String colorHash = "#"+Integer.toHexString((int)(o.getDouble("fillOpacity")*255))+o.getString("color").replace("#","");
                polygon.setFillColor(Color.parseColor(colorHash));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){}

    }
}
```